# Remove last slug of url with php basename

Tags: php, regex

So I need to remove the last slug of a URL if it matches /amp.

I can get the full URL with

```
$domain.  parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH )
```

and the last slug with basename

```
basename(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH))
```

is there to echo everything up to the slug /amp and leave that off.

Eg. domain.com/blog/this-is-a-post/amp becomes domain.com/blog/this-is-a-post

Comment: make a clear question please

Comment: How do you mean combine them? I only ask because it looks like you have already combined them??

Comment: `dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])`?